# R: Panel unit root test with unbalanced data due to late entry into the sample

Tags: r, panel-data, unit-root, plm

I would like to conduct a panel unit root test on the price constituents of the Dow Jones Industrial Index, which is composed of 30 stocks. The index spans 20 years, and stocks drop out of the index as others replace them. So over time, the index will be made up of different stocks.

Assuming also that there is a high chance that the individual series (i.e., prices of the index constituents) are somewhat correlated with one another, what is the right way to conduct a panel unit root test in R talking into account the unbalanced nature of the data and the potential of dependence between the individual series?

Comment: Have a look at package `plm`, functions `purtest` and `cipstest`, and check if one of the implemented methods suites your needs (sounds like you want `cipstest` which implementes the cross-sectionally augmented Im, Pesaran and Shin (IPS) test (Pesaran MH (2007)).

Comment: This seems relevant (self-promotion alert :-)):https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/141761/unit-root-test-for-unbalanced-panel-data/141836#141836

Comment: This actually is implemented in package `plm` as well as function `phansitest`.